# Spring MVC request mapping explicitly disallowing parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm running into a Spring (3.1) mapping conundrum: 
I have a simple, findAll method:

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET )
@ResponseBody
public List< User > findAll(){
    return findAllInternal();
}
```

This maps on the following URI (which is good): `/user`.

However it also maps on: `/user?bla=8`, which is not good.

Is there a way to explicitly specify the fact that this particular mapping contains no parameters? 
I have tried to specify the `params` in the `@RequestMapping` but I can see no clear way of doing this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks. 
Eugen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can negate parameters in `@RequestMapping.param` attribute.

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "!bla")
```

As of spring 3.1 you can't explicitly disallow request to have parameters.

But to be honest it's rarely necessary.

There are three use cases:

1. `bla` is a known parameter that you can explicitly allow/disallow.
2. `bla` is unknown parameter and can be ignored.
3. you want to handle requests with unknown parameters in a special way (throw an error for example).

The first two can be done in spring mvc. The third one, AFAIK, can't.

The third option is also potentially dangerous as you'd have to be really careful about the parameters the clients can send to your sever (like stuff added by security frameworks, etc).

Comment: Yes, "!bla" would disallow the "bla" parameter; unfortunately this doesn't help because, as you rightly point out, bla is not really a know parameter. Also, not sure about this kind of mapping rarely being needed - this particular service is a pretty standard service - findAll again, pretty standard, and so a client, consuming the API and doing things like: "/user?someUnknownParameter=someUnknownValue" will get the results from "/user" - which means he would get all the users in the system and the parameter would be ignored - which is a little unexpected

Comment: @Eugen it's not really that unexpected. My impression is that most sites ignore unknown params.

Comment: Agreed - I was just hoping that I could get a REST API to behave a little differently (out of the box). Thanks.