# How to hide @RequestMapping parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Servlet with a parameter bean. The bean has some fields that should no be able to override by the users get-query.

How can I achieve it?

None of the following worked:

```
@JsonIgnore
@XmlTransient
@JsonIgnoreProperties
private String somefield;
```

Run:

```
localhost:8080/myservlet?somefield=xxx
```

This will alter the property directly. How can I tell spring to skip that property?

Or even better: let spring reject the request as the user tried to change an unallowed property?

Comment: Have you considered declaring it as `final`?

Comment: I'm overriding those field outside of the class, with values from injected `@Value` parameters. So cannot make them final in the req.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see it.

Comment: See the below link, which may helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11294332/2935802

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by *servlet* you mean **controller** you can configure binder to ignore some properties of model class:

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setDisallowedFields("somefield");
    }

    @GetMapping("/myservlet")
    public String myservlet(Model model) {
        return model.toString();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Model {
    private String somefield;
    private String property2;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Another way is to remove the ignored property setter from model class at all. In that case spring will not be able to set the value.

If by *servlet* you mean **servlet** then just wrap the request excluding ignoring properties from `getParameterMap()` call.

**Update**

If you want to force spring to reject entire request when inappropriate property is set then you can register a custom property editor for this very property and throw an exception within setValue method. Like this:

```
@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    // binder.setDisallowedFields("property1");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "somefield", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        @Override
        public void setValue(Object value) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    });
}
```

Another way is to throw an exception within property setter in `Model` class. Spring then catch it, wrap into its own `org.springframework.validation.BindException` and return with `400 bad request`.

Comment: Ok that works ignoring the params. But is it at well possible to throw an exception if someone tries to set those params via get-query?